# Emoji (Unicode) to UTF-8 ampersand hash (?) encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace, urlencode, emoji

To maintain compatibility with a pre-existing PHP solution, I require

input:  `// emoji character`,
output: **`&#xF0;&#x9F;&#x98;&#x81;`**

I believe this is 'ampersand hash' encoding (I'm not sure that's what it's called.. I'll be damned if I can find any resources which explain how I arrive at this format... or why what this encoding is suitable for...)

I can get the bytes by URL-encoding the Unicode...

```
<?php  print urlencode(""); /* Output: %F0%9F%98%81 */  ?>
```

...and I can use a Regex to convert this to the format I need... but I don't like this solution. It's very hacky and very prone to accidentally encoding non-encoded strings...

```
<?php
  $enc = urlencode("");
  print $enc; // %F0%9F%98%81
  $find = '/(%)([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])/i';
  $replacement = '&#x$2;';
  print preg_replace($find,$replacement,$enc);
?>
```

**Result: `&#xF0;&#x9F;&#x98;&#x81`**

Is there a better approach?

What is this encoding known as, and how do I arrive at it (via PHP)?

Many thanks!

**Edit:** Turns out this approach is unsuitable after all. `urlencode` converts all the spaces into `+` characters. There must be a correct approach to arrive at this format?

Comment: I've never seen anything like `&#xF0;&#x9F;&#x98;&#x81;` Two closest things are %-encoding (%F0%9F%98%81) and numeric character entity   reference (&#x1f601;) for XML and HTML.

Comment: Your format it is invalid. As in comment from Tom (but expanded), you should translate the character into `&x1f601;` (as character, also if in UTF-8 it will be encoded into 4 bytes) The page http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php has some example on how to get the character from a string. Warning ugly code, and usual quality of comments on PHP site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#xF0;&#x9F;&#x98;&#x81;` is "html entities"; it represents the 4 hex bytes F09F9891, which is the UTF-8 encoding for that Emoji.  I suspect it is HTML, not PHP that you are trying to appease?

http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%F0%9F%98%81 -- go part way down the page to "string stuff" to see how to encode it for HTML, utf8, python, javascript, etc.

One way in PHP is:

```
echo bin2hex('');   // f09f9881
```

Then break it into groups of 2 hex digits.